# Determining special characters

Tags: unicode, encoding, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

Once in a while I come across special characters, e.g. `^@` which I know is null. Often times it is a character I don't know, such as `^L`. Does anybody know of a way to translate these characters into their unicode equivalents? I'm viewing the characters in `vi` on a RHEL system. The application runs on Java.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with Unicode.  It was common in olden Unix text editors, the way they display ASCII control characters.  Codes less than 0x20, they simply add 0x40 and put ^ in front of it.  So 0x00 == ^ + 0x40 = ^@.  ^M would be common for example, 0x0d, the carriage return control code.  Not much you can do with it unless you have a-priori knowledge that the program that emits text like this *doesn't* use Unicode :)  And still a bummer if ^ was intentional, this was made for programmer's eyes.

Comment: The character I was trying to figure out was `^L`. `L` is 0x4c, therefore 0x4c -0x40 = 0xc. And 0xc is FF NP form feed, new page. I got that right?

Comment: Yes, `^L` is form feed.  Another way to think of it is L is the 12th (0xC) letter of the alphabet, but doesn't help with `^[`.